# How to refresh a page using Flask and MQTT?

Tags: python, html, flask, mqtt

Working on a school assignment and I'm using flask and MQTT. I need to be able to read an input from any device sending an MQTT message and change the status of the page. It works when I have this as my code:

```
<body>
<h1>Led Status</h1> 
    {% if data == 'on' %}
            <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL='/led/on';" />
    {% elif data == 'off' %}
            <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL='/led/off';" />
</body>
```

But it gets stuck in an infinite loop where the page just refreshes constantly. So I tried using a for loop as seen here:

```
<body>
<h1>Led Status</h1> 
{% for x in y %}
    {% if data == 'on' %}
            <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL='/led/on';" />
    {% elif data == 'off' %}
            <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL='/led/off';" />
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

But when I use the for loop the code doesn't even run at all resulting in the webpage staying the same as it was before.

Any help here?

Comment: Why, in the first block do you have `{% endfor %}` when you don't even have a `for` loop?

Comment: fixed that it still doesn't work.

Comment: That tag would have thrown an error so now I'm not sure what to trust in your [mcve]. Can you confirm that this is _actually_ representative?

Comment: Is variable `y` defined? On which you are iterating the loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do the subscription in the backend (Flask).

Add a Javascript MQTT over Websockets client to the page and update the content of the page directly when a new message is received without having to reload the page at all.

Comment: How exactly can I do this?

Comment: Since this is school work, I suggest you do a little research. I've pointed you in the front direction, I'm not going to just hand you an answer